# Facebook SDK for PHP 5: returned an error: No URL set

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I am following Facebook's SDK, but I am receiving the following error:

> No URL set.

Here is the code:

```
<?php

    require_once __DIR__ . '/src/autoload.php';

    session_start();

    $fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
        'app_id' => '',
        'app_secret' => '',
        'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
    ]);

    // Use one of the helper classes to get a Facebook\Authentication\AccessToken entity.
    $helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
    //$helper = $fb->getJavaScriptHelper();
    //$helper = $fb->getCanvasHelper();
    //$helper = $fb->getPageTabHelper();

    try {
        // Get the Facebook\GraphNodes\GraphUser object for the current user.
        // If you provided a 'default_access_token', the '{access-token}' is optional.
        $response = $fb->get('/me', '{access-token}');
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    } catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }

    $me = $response->getGraphUser();
    echo 'Logged in as ' . $me->getName();
?>
```

**Why am I receiving this error?**

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not redirecting to right login url

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
    'app_id' => '',
    'app_secret' => '',
    'default_graph_version' => 'v2.2',
]);

$helper = $fb->getRedirectLoginHelper();
$permissions = ['email', 'public_profile'];

$callback = 'http://yoursite.com/callbackscript.php < your file';

$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl($callback, $permissions);

<a href="<?= $loginUrl; ?>">Login with Facebook!</a>
```

Comment: I created a file login.php with what you wrote. Nothing changes

Comment: Are you callbacking then? That code what you provide is callbackscript.php

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure `php_curl.dll` extension is enabled in php.ini